# No results for basic query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to set up a basic Elasticsearch index locally and using Kibana, I am able to get all results when I do a match_all search, but I've tried many variations of a simple match query and none work.

My mapping:

```
{
  "recipes-v1": {
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "ingredients": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "instructions": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results from a match_all query:

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "recipes-v1",
        "_id": "0",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "Name": "Alfredo Sauce",
          "Description": "Cheesy alfredo sauce that is delicious. Definitely not vegan",
          "Ingredients": [
            "1/2 cup butter",
            "3 cloves garlic"
          ],
          "Instructions": [
            "Melt butter in a saucepan then add heavy cream and combine on medium low heat",
            "Let the mixture simmer for 2 minutes then add garlic, salt, pepper, and italian seasoning to taste. Let simmer until fragrent (about 1 minute)"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "recipes-v1",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "Name": "Shrimp Scampi",
          "Description": "Definitely not just Gordon Ramsay's shrimp scampi minus capers",
          "Ingredients": [
            "1 lb shrimp",
            "2 lemons"
          ],
          "Instructions": [
            "Do things",
            "Do more things"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried deleting the index and recreating it and every variation of Alfredo, alfredo, alfredo sauce, AlfredoSauce, etc. and none have worked. Please help
All variations in these queries yield no hits though:

```
POST recipes-v1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "alfredo"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
POST recipes-v1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "match": {
          "name": "alfredo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT/UPDATE:**
I changed the document fields to be all lowercase and the problem persists. However, if I set dynamic mapping to True with a new index, everything works. The mapping is now this and works, but I would like still like to know why my static mapping did not work, as eventually I'd want to make this static.

```
{
  "recipes-v1": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "ingredients": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "instructions": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your documents contains field names that are capital-cased, i.e. `Description`, `Ingredients`, etc

Your mapping contains the same field names but lowercased, i.e. `description`, `ingredients`, etc and has dynamic mapping disabled (`dynamic: false`) so new fields will not be created and indexed dynamically.

You need to either change your mapping or your documents so that both have the **exact same field names**.

Comment: I updated the documents to be lower case as well and I still get no hits. The change is reflected in the match_all results.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the changes you've done and what you're getting